# Pycharm: How to open a Python console with a program

Tags: python, pycharm

When I open a python console, pycharm executes the following in a terminal:

```
/Some/Path/python3.7 /Path/To/Some/Script/Like/pydevconsole.py --mode=client --port=34215
```

How can I edit this to get it to run with a program like **vglrun**, so that it looks like:

```
/opt/VirtualGL/bin/vglrun /Some/Path/python3.7 /Path/To/Some/Script/Like/pydevconsole.py --mode=client --port=34215
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sergey Karpov from JetBrains
"You can't. It is possible to customize Starting script in File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console | Python Console, but not possible to use another executable."

[Link to his answer](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006661379-How-to-open-a-Python-console-with-a-program)

But running vlgrun with pycharm does actually the trick for me.